# How to extract one column from a jagged array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a jagged array which is basically just a matrix with m rows and n columns (I know I could have used a normal matrix but I read that matrix multiplication is faster using a jagged array).

I'd like to extract every row from only one column without using a for loop. How is this accomplished. Also, please explain the code because I found an answer that claims that the following should work but I cannot figure out how to adapt it to my situation.

```
object[] column = Enumerable.Range(0, myArray.GetLength(0))
                            .Select(rowNum => (object)myArray[daily.m, daily.n])
                            .ToArray();
```

Okay so the following answer doesn't seem to give me errors but now I'm running into another problem:

```
var selectedArray = myArray.Where(o => (o != null && o.Count() > daily.dependentVarIndex)).Select(o => o[daily.dependentVarIndex]).ToArray();
            Method1 m1 = new Method1(13);
            for (int i = 0; i < daily.m; i++)
            {
                m1.do(selectedArray[i]); //this give me an error
            }
```

How can I now index the object "selectedArray"? Note that I defined Method1, the fxn "do" earlier in my code.

Comment: do you know what is the index of your column ? or you just want all rows for a random column ?

Comment: it looks like a multidimensional array to me.

Comment: Strange code. You are not using `rowNum` anywhere. And what is `daily`?

Comment: daily is just an object I created from a class I defined. Anything that seems mysterious is something I defined before. Sorry about the confusion but I think that part of my question has been answered anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Using lambda:

```
var jaggedArray = new int[5][];
jaggedArray[0] = new[] { 1, 2, 3 }; // 3 item array
jaggedArray[1] = new[] { 7, 6 };
jaggedArray[3] = new int[10]; // 10 item array of 0's

const int selectItem = 0;
var selectedArray = jaggedArray
    .Where(o => (o != null && o.Count() > selectItem))
    .Select(o => o[selectItem])
    .ToArray();
```

Following array should contain 3 items

> [1, 7, 0]

Comment: Don't forget bounds checking

Comment: Thanks, I think this works. But I tried to access selectedArray so I could print out a couple points to ensure it's what I want and I get an error saying the number of indices is still 2-dimensional. But isn't it now technically just a vector?

Answer (score 0):

```
int [][] jaggedArray = /* SNIP */

jaggedArray.Select(row => row.Length >= ZERO_INDEXED_COLUMN_NO + 1
                           ? (int?)row[ZERO_INDEXED_COLUMN_NO]
                           : null)
           .ToArray();
```

where `ZERO_INDEXED_COLUMN_NO` is the zero-indexed number of column you wish to retrieve. The result is an array of `(int?)` with a `null` value where a given row is to short to have the `ZERO_INDEXED_COLUMN_NO` entry.

Comment: can we just for a second assume that it's the zero-indexed number of column you wish to retrieve? I appreciate that there's no such thing as self-documenting code, but, sheesh, I believe this one's pretty obvious. EDIT: made it more clear, hopefully.